# Confused about drawing line segments?

Tags: inkscape

I am a newbie to Inkscape. I have a problem when drawing line with Inkscape.
[image]

want to draw a picture like this. But I don't know how to make the line and the inside of the line show different colors. If I directly use the color palette under the interface, the area surrounded by the line segment is changed to that color. If I use shift+click on the color swatch below, the outside and inside of the line segment are adjusted to the same color. I want the lines and the interior to show different colors, like the picture above (black and gray). Also, I cannot change the length of one side of the line segment in the picture above. If I lengthen one side, the other side will become longer accordingly. Can someone teach me? Thank you!

I still have a stupid question. I think maybe it is not appropriate to open a separate question to ask. I can’t adjust the position of the picture. I use the arrow -> <- on the keyboard, the color palette will move, and the picture will not move. How can I move the part of my concern to the middle?

Comment: how did you draw the arrow? what version of inkscape are you using?

Comment: I use tools for drawing Bezier curves and straight lines. The version is 1.0.1. The picture above is imported from a screenshot of a paper, I want to draw the same picture

Answer (score 6):

There are several possible ways to do this. Here I'll concentrate on using some path effects and filters to do this. This method allows you to create a re-usable element you can duplicate and adjust any way you want.

1. Draw a path like this with the Bézier tool, and apply a thick stroke

[image]

2. Add a small arrow head marker in the stroke panel
3. Set the stroke to grey
4. Open the Path Effects panel (Ctrlt+&), click the + button to add a *Corners Fillet/Chamfer* path effect, then click and drag the corners to round them

[image]

[image]

5. Do *Filters > Morphology > Outline*, like this

[image]

6. Do *Filters > Shadows and Glows > Drop Shadow* like this

[image]

7. And now you have an arrow which can be adjusted any way you want

[image]